# How to put Kubernetes Dashboard behind a secure authentication?

Tags: kubernetes

I recently installed Kubernetes using Kubernetes Operations tool, but when I installed Kubernetes Dashboard using [this](https://rawgit.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml) script, the dashboard endpoints were in a private cluster.

Is there a way I can expose this dashboard over a public network using something like a service type `LoadBalancer` and put it behind a password or a secure authentication?

There is a lot that can be done with such a Dashboard, which is why I would like it behind a secure endpoint.

Answer (score 6):

You can easily accomplish that with [Ingress](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/) coupled with [NginX IngressController](https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ingress/controllers/nginx)

if you use something like :

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: dashboard.mydomain.tld
  namespace: kube-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: "Auth required"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: htpasswd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: dashboard.mydomain.tld
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: <dashsvc>
          servicePort: <dashport>
```

alongside with a proper `htpasswd` secret as indicated by auth-secret annotation

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: htpasswd
  namespace: kube-system
type: Opaque
data:
  auth: <your htpasswd base64>
```

note: You need a working ingress controller setup prior to using this for exposing your service to the world. You can also easily combine it with `kube-lego` for automated `https` support so your service is exposed over secured channel.

Comment: I tried following this but after the ingress rule is configured the page does not load and just sits there spinning then eventually timing out. The ingress controller is definitely working.